# Hyperopt retuns floats when it should not?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters, hyperopt

When I run Hyperopt on a RandomForest I get these hyperparameter values in return (best_run). Why do I get floats when it makes no sense to have 618.23 trees in a RandomForest.

Is it due to how I define the search space?

```
{'RF_max_depth': 7.667424854133456,
 'RF_min_samples_leaf': 2.5521665615823688,
 'RF_min_samples_split': 3.9654757302547887,
 'RF_n_estimators': 618.2370650258832,
 'classifier': 1}
```

My search space looks like this:

```
search_space = hp.choice('clf', [
  {
    'type':'XGBoost',
    'n_estimators': scope.int(hp.quniform('XGB_n_estimators', 100, 1000, 1)),
    'learning_rate': hp.loguniform('XGB_learning_rate', -3, 0),
    'max_depth': scope.int(hp.quniform('XGB_max_depth', 2, 14, 1)),
  },

  {
    'type':'RandomForest',
    'n_estimators':scope.int(hp.uniform('RF_n_estimators',100,1000)),
    'max_depth':scope.int(hp.uniform('RF_max_depth',2,14)),
    'min_samples_leaf':scope.int(hp.uniform('RF_min_samples_leaf',1,5)),
    'min_samples_split':scope.int(hp.uniform('RF_min_samples_split',2,6)),
  }
])
```